# How to find the selected row index of a grid in Dojo

Tags: datagrid, dojo

I am relatively new to Dojo. I am using a DataGrid, where in I have a textbox in one of the columns. I want to know the row index of the grid when the user enters some data in the textinput of that particular row.

```
'name' : 'Partner Column Name',
'field' : 'text',
'width' : '25%',
'field' : 'partnerColumnName',
'text-align': 'center',
'editable' : true,
'type' : dojox.grid.cells._Widget,
'formatter' : function()                             
{
 return new dijit.form.TextBox({style:"width:100%", id: "textBox_"+counter++,          onChange: function ()
{
  // Here I want to know the row index of the grid. 
}
```

Can someone help me in this respect.

Thanks,
Nirmal Kumar Bhogadi

Answer (score 0):

When viewing the code of the datagrid ([`dojox/grid/cells/_Base`](https://github.com/dojo/dojox/blob/master/grid/cells/_base.js) to be precise) I noticed that the `formatter` callback gets two parameters:

- The original value
- The row index (`inRowIndex`)

So based on that you can easily retrieve the row index, for example:

```js
formatter: function(myValue, rowIndex) {
    // Do something with rowIndex
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the whole selected row data of your grid? This is what I use in my project:

```
var grid = dijitRegistry.byId('yourGridId');    
if (!grid || !grid.selection || grid.selection.getSelected()) {
    console.log(grid.selection.getSelected());
}
```